# Change newtheorem numbering order in Arabic : from Right to Left

Tags: luatex

Can i change the order of numbering using LuaLaTex

```
\setcounter{section}{3}
\setcounter{subsection}{2}      
\newtheorem{thm}{مبرهنة}[subsection]
```

and the result should be looks like

> مبرهنة 1.2.3

thanks in advance guys

Comment: The `thmtools`  package  might help. See `headformat` on p.13 of the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't provide a MWE or say what packages you are using. In case it's `babel`, you may need the option `layout=counters`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=counters]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, main]{arabic}
\babelfont{rm}{FreeSerif}

\newtheorem{thm}{مبرهنة}[subsection]

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{3}
\setcounter{subsection}{2}    

\begin{thm}
   ABC.
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}
   DEF.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks you solved it